# Why can't I upload a picture with selenium? PROBLEM FIXED

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

my previous code looks like this, but I cannot upload an image. The script breaks off at this point, I already have several options and try unfortunately without success

I work with VS Code on Ubuntu

```
myvariable1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/form/ul[9]/div/li[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]")
myvariable1.send_keys("/home/username/Schreibtisch/myfolder/1.png")
```

The html code looks like this ----

```
<div class="fileuploader fileuploader-theme-dragdrop">
```

```
<input

class="gallery_media"

type="file"

name="files[]"

tabindex="-1"

accept="image/*"

multiple="multiple"

style="position: absolute; z-index: -9999; height: 0px; width: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; line-height: 0; outline: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0;"

/>
```

```
<div class="fileuploader-input-inner">

  <div class="fileuploader-main-icon"></div>

  <h3 class="fileuploader-input-caption onDesktop"><span class="onDesktop">Bilder hierher ziehen und ablegen</span></h3>

  <p class="onDesktop">oder</p>

  <div class="fileuploader-input-button"><span>Datei auswählen</span></div>

  </div>

 </div>

<div class="fileuploader-items"><ul class="fileuploader-items-list"></ul></div>
```

Comment: Is this specifically a drag and drop file format?

Comment: No, a file can also be selected normally, but drag and drop is also possible

Comment: Got it, does your send keys command populate the input field?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, I haven't been that long on the subject of Python :)

Comment: For "myvariable1" does your send keys command send the keys to the input? Or is it blank? Also, you should add more of your code in the question such as the URL

Comment: You'll want to send the path to the <input type="file"> tag... looks like you've targeted a DIV tag.

Comment: /input At the end of that xpath would go to that input tag or //input[@class='galley_media'] could target it if it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
myvariable1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/form/ul[9]/div/li[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
myvariable1.send_keys("C:/home/username/Schreibtisch/myfolder/1.png")
```

Go down into input otherwise you'll get a Noninteractable exception and then send the absolute file path to your file.